# 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/DEFAULT WEB SITE/{WebApiName}' has shutdown

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, iis-10

I'm having problems in a developed WebAPI running in the IIS.
I've developed this WebAPI in:
net6.0
and
net7.0
App manages Json web Tokens

Users make request to this webAPI but after while, they get the response: "503 Server has been shutdown".
Checking the server I can see, IIS is running but something with application pool went wrong. For running again I can recycle pool app and it works againt, but after some requests this happen again.

Checking the Server application logs the only message is: "Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/DEFAULT WEB SITE/{WebApiName}' has shutdown"

For trying to control this issue, I've changed some IIS configurations:
App Pool:

- .NET CRL Version: 4.0
- Start Mode: Always Running
- Idle Timeout (minutes): 0
- Recycling conditions / Fixed Intervals / Regular Time(minutes): 1

IIS Site:

- Preload Enabled: True

So, if server has shuted down (according the error message), this configuration its running again. But users keep reporting this problem.

So, please I would like how can I manage this problem,
Any Idea??

Comment: might check here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/asp-net-core-503-server-has-been-shutdown/ba-p/3830338

Comment: In addition to the application logs, check the Windows Event Viewer for any system-level errors or warnings that might provide more insight into the cause of the shutdowns. Look for any relevant logs and error messages to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys... The problem was caused, because in constructor method for dependency injection I had some values or parameters. I was taking values from appsettings.json to classes and controllers, I didn't know that this is a problem in production environment. If you know techniques for taking values from appsettings.json to the rest of the app, please let me know.